# google.load search <script>

Tags: javascript, google-loader

What does the following do

```
google.load("search", "1");
```

Can i access this directly via a `<script/>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of the [Google Loader](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/) service, which allows a JavaScript script to load other common JS script (in this case, the Google AJAX Search API I believe).